# MessageListener in asmack to integrate facebook chat not able to bind to any widget

Tags: facebook, xmpp, asmack

I am working in an android application and I want to integrate facebook chat in it.For that I am using asmack-jse-buddycloud-2010.12.11. I am able to sent and receive chats. But I am not able to bind it to any view(Toast,ListView etc..). The received message is inside the MessageListener, And I am not able to bind it in any of the view.

Please look into my code :

```
   public void SentFBMessage(String message) {

    Chat newChat = mObjChatManager.createNewChat(
                    "-100001303337607@chat.facebook.com", new MessageListener() {
        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
            Log.e("Received message: ", message.getBody());
               **Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message.getBody(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();**}
        });
    try {
            newChat.sendMessage(message);
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                System.out.println("Error Delivering block");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically your problem is the new MessageListener you are making every time. Put the listener in a class of its own and just add it every time.

```
connection.getChatManager().addChatListener(new ChatManagerListener() {
    @Override
    public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean b) {
        chat.addMessageListener(messageListener);
    }
});
```